# Print proper mathematical formatting

Tags: ipython, sympy

When I use `sympy` to get the square root of 8, the output is ugly:

`2*2**(1/2)`

```
import sympy

In [2]: sympy.sqrt(8)

Out[2]: 2*2**(1/2)
```

Is there any way to make `sympy` print output in proper mathematical notation (i.e. using the proper symbol for square root) ?

## UPDATE:

when I follow the [suggestions](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/printing.html) from @pqnet:

```
from sympy import *
x, y, z = symbols('x y z')
init_printing()
init_session()
```

I get following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-21d886bf3e54> in <module>()
      2 x, y, z = symbols('x y z')
      3 init_printing()
----> 4 init_session()

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/interactive/session.pyc in init_session(ipython, pretty_print, order, use_unicode, quiet, argv)
    154                 # and False means don't add the line to IPython's history.
    155                 ip.runsource = lambda src, symbol='exec': ip.run_cell(src, False)
--> 156                 mainloop = ip.mainloop
    157             else:
    158                 mainloop = ip.interact

AttributeError: 'ZMQInteractiveShell' object has no attribute 'mainloop'
```

Comment: you mean, like a graphical display?

Comment: @pqnet - well, I don't know what you call "graphical display". What I have in mind, is to have mathematical symbol for square root printed instead of the `sqrt()` code.

Comment: I wanted to say, do you want some graphical rendering of the result, or just want it to be output in unicode like this: `2*√(2)`

Comment: @pqnet - oh, I see. I would like to have graphical rendering of the result

Comment: check [this](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/printing.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an ipython notebook you can enable Sympy's graphical math typesetting with the `init_printing` function:

```
import sympy
sympy.init_printing(use_latex='mathjax')
```

After that, sympy will intercept the output of each cell and format it using math fonts and symbols. Try:

```
sympy.sqrt(8)
```

*See also:*

- [Printing section](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/printing.html) in the [Sympy Tutorial](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it is this:

```
sympy.pprint(sympy.sqrt(8))
```

For me (using rxvt-unicode and ipython) it gives

```
    ___
2⋅╲╱ 2
```

Comment: I get lots of errors, such as `UnsupportedOperation`, and many more

Comment: Interesting, what terminal emulator are you using? and what python shell?

Comment: I am using `ipython notebook`

Comment: It works fine for me with ipython notebook in chrome. You could try updating your version of sympy, python, ipython or your browser? Or try running in a different browser or with all addons disabled? Other than that I don't think I can help sorry.